# python: Error while converting bytes array to json format

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to convert bytes array to json by following the [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj0-f2vzpL4AhUrmIQIHbBUDeoQFnoECAYQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F40059654%2Fpython-convert-a-bytes-array-into-json-format&usg=AOvVaw00ZAUO6l9SD2MGlUWBjZ37)

Below is the code:

```
command = "my command"
    my_bytes_value = self.subprocess_cmd(command)
    print("OUTPUT----")
    print(my_bytes_value)
    my_json = my_bytes_value.decode('utf8').replace("'", '"')
    print('- ' * 20)

    # Load the JSON to a Python list & dump it back out as formatted JSON
    #milestone 1
    data = json.loads(my_json)
    s = json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
    print(s)
```

I am getting below error, also some print statement is executing

```
    File "1.py", line 50, in getlogs
    data = json.loads(my_json)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.12_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.12_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.12_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
OUTPUT----
b'signing string: (request-target): post /v2/search\\ndate: Sat, 04 Jun 2022 05:41:48 GMT\\nhost: example.com\\nx-content-sha256: askhKJADKJ/Bdm+sdlfkhlkh1376/m6ti5fo=\\ncontent-type: application/json\\ncontent-length: 342\n[ {\n  "timestamp" : "2022-06-04T05:16:50.522Z",\n  "segmentPartitionId" : null,\n  "component" : null,\n  "region" : null,\n  "availabilityDomain" : null,\n  "filename" : null,\n  "casperUrl" : null,\n  "host" : null,\n  "source" : "EventStats: \\n Some message String\\nSome message String\\n",\n  "fullSource" : "{\\"cursor\\":-2002349868963,\\"bucket\\":\\"xyz\\",\\"kafkaAd\\":\\"gr-10\\",\\"kafkaOffset\\":239846986,\\"kafkaPartition\\":15,\\"kafkaRecord\\":273,\\"kafkaTopic\\":\\"logs\\",\\"lineOffset\\":2343,\\"logGroup\\":\\"dev_log\\",\\"logStreamId\\":\\"xdfklhklsdhfkl\\",\\"logType\\":\\"STANDARD\\",\\"namespace\\":\\"dev-api\\",\\"rawSource\\":\\"{\\\\\\"logpersisting\\\\\\":\\\\\\"some_logs\\\\\\",\\\\\\"level\\\\\\":\\\\\\"INFO\\\\\\",\\\\\\"logger\\\\\\":\\\\\\"com.example.CollectorTaskHelper\\\\\\",\\\\\\"msg\\\\\\":\\\\\\"LogStats: \\\\\\\\n Some message String\\\\\\\\nSome message String\\\\\\\\n\\\\\\",\\\\\\"ts\\\\\\":1243454354,\\\\\\"workflowid\\\\\\":\\\\\\"12345\\\\\\",\\\\\\"workflowstepname\\\\\\":\\\\\\"LOG_ALERTS\\\\\\"}\\",\\"resource\\":\\"askjgjf\\",\\"tenant\\":\\"xyz\\",\\"ts\\":123214234,\\"tsIndexed\\":239486986,\\"tsIngested\\":324868623,\\"#eventpersisting\\":\\"exadata_events\\",\\"#level\\":\\"INFO\\",\\"#logger\\":\\"com.example\\",\\"#thread\\":\\"flow-Processor-Thread-137\\",\\"#workflowid\\":\\"8kjhsdf76784378\\",\\"#flowname\\":\\"CollectorWorkflowV2\\",\\"#flownodename\\":\\"example.com\\",\\"#workflowstepname\\":\\"LOG_ALERTS\\"}"\n} ]'


- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

Process finished with exit code 1
```

So, upto milestone it is working fine but not working after that. Looks like some character is spoiling here. but not able to identify it.

Comment: is it possible to avoid all of this by using [`requests`](https://pypi.org/project/requests/)? `j = requests.get().to_json()`

Comment: I am using shell script to collect output. So, as of now it is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it isn't working in your case is because your string isn't properly formatted json even after making the adjustments you found in that other post.

There is a some json in the string though, so depending on if you really need the full part of the string or not your could do this.

```
command = "my command"
    my_bytes_value = self.subprocess_cmd(command)
    print("OUTPUT----")
    print(my_bytes_value)
    print('- ' * 20)

    # Load the JSON to a Python list & dump it back out as formatted JSON
    #milestone 1
    text = my_bytes_value.decode('utf-8')
    my_json = json.loads(text[text.index("[") :])
    my_json[0]["fullSource"] = json.loads(my_json[0]["fullSource"])
    my_json[0]["fullSource"]["rawSource"] = json.loads(my_json[0]["fullSource"]["rawSource"])
    print(my_json)
    json.dumps(my_json, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I found after converting from byte to string, first line is not part of json string, so i removed it. After that I am able to convert it into json

```
command = "my command"
my_bytes_value = self.subprocess_cmd(command)
print("OUTPUT----")
print(my_bytes_value)
list1 = my_bytes_value.decode('utf8').replace("'", '"').split('\n')[1:]
my_json = ''.join(list1)
print('- ' * 20)

# Load the JSON to a Python list & dump it back out as formatted JSON
#milestone 1
data = json.loads(my_json)
s = json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
print(s)
```

Comment: You are doing pretty much the same thing except you aren't deserializing the inner parts of the dictionary.  After the first `json.loads` call there is still alot of serialized text inside the dictionary.